# HTML load the content of a div in a html file into another html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Recently I started learning a little of HTML, and I have a little doubt. My intention is to make in the first page a section div which can change depending of the element that you click on a menu (instead of carrying you to another HTML).
I've tried a few things with javascript to see if I could make it work, but I don't achieve anything despite that in other posts that is the given solution.

This is what i have so far:

```css
.sideNav {
 position: fixed;
 width: 250px;
 height: 100vh;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 background-color: red;
 top: 60px;
}

.contentWrapper {
 margin: 60px 0 0 250px;
 padding: 0 30px;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset = utf-8>
  <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "./assets/stylesheets/main.css">
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function toggleMenu(id) {
    var menuBox = document.getElementById(id);
    if(menuBox.style.display == "block") {
     menuBox.style.display = "none";
    } else {
     menuBox.style.display = "block";
    }
   }
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $(".menuAnchor").on("click", function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#contentWrapper").load("food.html" + " #contentWrapper");
        return false;
          )};
         )};
  </script>
  <title>The Nest</title>
  
  
 </head>
 <body>
  <aside class = "sideNav">
   <div>
    <a class = "menuAnchor"  onclick = "toggleMenu('foodMenu')"> Food</a>
    <ul class = "menuBox" id = "foodMenu" style = "display : none">
     <li>
      <a id = "burguer" href = "#">Burguer</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a id = "hotDog" href = "#">Hot Dog</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a id = "pizza" href = "#">Pizza</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </aside>
  <div id = "contentWrapper">
   <section class = "contentWrapper">
    d
   </section>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

This is the other HTML file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
 <body>
  <div id = "contentWrapper">  
   <section class = "contentWrapper">
    <h1>Food</h1>
    
    <article id = "burguer">
     <h2>Burguer</h2>
     <p>
      Burguer
     </p>
    </article>
    <article id = "hotDog">
     <h2>Hot Dog</h2>
     <p>
      Hot Dog
     </p>
    </article>
    <article id = "pizza">
     <h2>Pizza</h2>
     <p>
      Pizza
     </p>
    </article>
   </section>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I wanted that, when i press the String (button in a future) the menu would cascade and the "p" that appear in the div section would change to the second HTML info, but I only could link to the other page.

As I said, part of those scripts seem to work as the script of the div load is around in other answers, but can't make it to work for me.

I'm unsure if what I'm doing and how I'm doing it is the best option.

Thank you and sorry for the trouble.

---

What I'm trying is to, having a main html with the head and the menus:

[Graphic for the main html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AI3HO.jpg)

Being the content changed with another from other html, let's say food, when one of the link in the menu is pressed.

Comment: Please expand on "can't make it work for me". Look at your console and see if there are any errors there.

Comment: You are trying to load "food.html#contentWrapper", but you have no such id in your sample HTML.  You have a div with the *class* "contentWrapper", and another with the id "contesntWrapper" - which is probably a typo, and if fixed would at least give you a matching element.

Comment: @Mike McCaughan I mean that, when looking for it, there are other posts of people looking seemingly the same, but using the scripts in the answers doesn't give me any result. There is a error in the snippet which I don't know the reason for, but in eclipse I get no error and the navigation through links works, aswell as the other script for expanding the menu.

Comment: @Paul Roub The "contesntWrapper" was a typo indeed. Already solved, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: So, in order for anyone to help you, you need to provide that error. Otherwise we're just guessing as to what the problem is. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking in quite unclear, however, I'll offer a solution based on my understanding of your question:

If you want to have some html that is used to replace the contents of a div, consider the template tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template

Templates are not displayed but can be accessed with jQuery (which I see you are using), for example:
html:

```
<div id="replace-area">
</div>
<template id="replace-content">
    <ol>
        <li>Here</li>
        <li>Are</li>
        <li>Some</li>
        <li>Items</li>
    </ol>
</template>
```

jQuery:

```
$("replace-area").html($("replace-content").clone().html());
```

With replace-area containing the content you want the user to see at the end and replace-content containing the content you want to put into replace-area.

This will result in:

```
<div id="replace-area">
    <ol>
        <li>Here</li>
        <li>Are</li>
        <li>Some</li>
        <li>Items</li>
    </ol>
</div>
<template id="replace-content">
    <ol>
        <li>Here</li>
        <li>Are</li>
        <li>Some</li>
        <li>Items</li>
    </ol>
</template>
```

With only the div being visible.

Hopefully this helps you get what you're after.